# How to implement power of two with logical shift in C?

Tags: c, logical-operators

I'm only starting with C, but what I'm doing now is a simple mathematical operation. What I want? I want the function that takes exponent and returns the power two. And I want to use, logical shift operator. [Wiki: Logical shifts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_shift)

> Logical shifts can be useful as efficient ways of performing
>   multiplication or division of unsigned integers by powers of two.
>   Shifting left by n bits on a signed or unsigned binary number has the
>   effect of multiplying it by 2n.

But there is one thing I can't understand, it doesn't work properly with big exponents, for example 32. Details in a code below. So, how can such function implemented right without using math library? Thanks in advance.

```
long power_of_two_ext(int exp) {
    exp = 32; // for testing purpose only

    long retL = pow(2, exp);
    printf("MATH pow() and long --->  %ld\n", retL);

    long retL2 = 1 << exp;
    printf("Shift bits left and long --->  %ld\n", retL2);

    long long retL3 = 1 << exp;
    printf("Left shift and long --->  %llu\n", retL3);
    return retL;
}

MATH pow() and long --->  4294967296
Left shift and long long --->  1
Left shift and long --->  1
```

Comment: Left shifting bit has its limits as you have found out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`1 << exp` is shifting an `int` left. Just because you're assigning the result to a `long` or `long long`, doesn't mean the expression is evaluated in that type. As written, your code's using `int`, and presumably you're running on a machine where `int` is 32 bits. [note: it's undefined behavior to shift left by an amount that's greater than or equal to the width of your integer type, so your code's behavior may not be consistent].

Instead, use constants of the right type to make sure your expressions are of the right type.

```
long retL2 = 1L << exp;
...
long long retL3 = 1LL << exp;
```